# Eliminar etiqueta <p> solo cuando contenga <figure><img></figure>

Tags: php, regex

Tengo esta estas etiquetas

```
<p><figure><img src="xxxx"></figure></p>
```

y quisiera cambiarlas por esto, es decir quitar las `<p></p>`

```
<figure><img src="xxxx"></figure>
```

pero solo cuando sea:

```
<p><figure><img></figure></p>
```

intenté con esta expresión regular, pero no lo conseguí:

```
<p><[^\/>][^>]*><\/[^>]+><\/p>
```

¿me podrían ayudar por favor?

Comment: Creo que la pregunta no es mala, pero, en este caso que uso le estas haciendo a esto?

Comment: hola, tengo un feed el cual es leido por facebook para los articulos instantaneos pero no acepta la etiqueta <figure> dentro de <p>

Comment: @skycomputer2 Es que, según **[el estándar](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element)**, una etiqueta `<p>` sólo puede tener **[contenido de frases](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-2)**, y `<figure>` no lo es, por lo que `<p><figure>...</figure></p>` es inválido (aunque la mayoría de los navegadores puedan renderizarlo bien)... Publiqué una respuesta que lo resuelve. No dudes en comentar cualquier cosa.

Answer (score 1):

No deberías usar expresiones regulares para procesar HTML. Tan sólo un pequeño cambio en el HTML haría que tu regex falle. Un espacio de más, un cambio en los atributos del tag, un comentario, o estructuras más complejas, harían que hasta un regex gigantesco no siga las reglas.

Es muy sencillo procesar HTML con **[DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)**, son las herramientas que están pensadas para eso.

Simplemente se genera el DOM así:

```
$html = '<p><figure><img src="xxxx"></figure></p>';

//Generar el DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$libxml_opciones = LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NONET | LIBXML_NOERROR;
@$dom->loadHTML($html, $libxml_opciones);
//Generar un XPath para búsquedas
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

Y se obtienen todos los `<p>` con:

```
$p_nodelist = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
```

Luego, los recorremos en un bucle (en orden inverso para conservar la estructura):

```
for ($i = $p_nodelist->length; --$i >= 0; ) {
    $p = $p_nodelist->item($i);
```

Viendo si cada `<p>` tiene un único hijo, y ese hijo es un `<figure>`:

```
    $p_hijos = $xpath->query('./*',$p);
    if ($p_hijos->length == 1 && $p_hijos->item(0)->tagName == 'figure') {
```

... realizando lo mismo con cada `<figure>`, si tiene un único hijo `<img>`.

Si se verifican las condiciones, reemplazamos el `<p>` por el `<figure>` hijo:

```
            $p->parentNode->replaceChild($figure,$p);
```

Por último, volvemos a pasar el DOM a un string:

```
$resultado = '';
foreach ($dom->documentElement->lastChild->childNodes as $elem) {
    $resultado .= $dom->saveHTML($elem);
}
```

---

Código:

```
<?php

$html = '<p><figure><img src="xxxx"></figure></p>';

//Generar el DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$libxml_opciones = LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NONET | LIBXML_NOERROR;
@$dom->loadHTML($html, $libxml_opciones);
//Generar un XPath para búsquedas
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);


//Obtener todos los tags <p>
$p_nodelist = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

//Bucle para cada <p> (en orden inverso para preservar la estructura)
for ($i = $p_nodelist->length; --$i >= 0; ) {
    $p = $p_nodelist->item($i);
    $p_hijos = $xpath->query('./*',$p);

    //Si el <p> tiene un único hijo, y ese hijo es un <figure>
    if ($p_hijos->length == 1 && $p_hijos->item(0)->tagName == 'figure') {
        $figure = $p_hijos->item(0);

        //Si el <figure> tiene un único hijo, y ese hijo es una <img>
        $figure_hijos = $xpath->query('./*',$figure);
        if ($figure_hijos->length == 1 && $figure_hijos->item(0)->tagName == 'img') {

            //REEMPLAZAR todo el <p> por solamente el <figure>
            $p->parentNode->replaceChild($figure,$p);

        }
    }
}

//Guardar el html
$resultado = '';
foreach ($dom->documentElement->lastChild->childNodes as $elem) {
    $resultado .= $dom->saveHTML($elem);
}

//Imprimir el resultado
echo $resultado;
```

Resultado:

```
<figure><img src="xxxx"></figure>
```

Demo:
https://3v4l.org/Jcacn

Answer (score 1):

Código php:

```
$str = '<p><img src="img/something.jpg" width="1249124" height="20" alt="foo" /></p>';
$str = preg_replace('%(.*?)<p>\s*(<img[^<]+?)\s*</p>(.*)%is', '$1$2$3', $str);
```

Fuente: [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130427/preg-replace-remove-p-tags-around-images)

Demo: https://3v4l.org/T4c9c

Explicación de la expresión regular (traducción):

```
Haga coincidir la expresión regular siguiente y capture su coincidencia en el número de referencia 1 «(. *?)»:

   Cualquier carácter que no sea un carácter de salto de línea «. *?» entre cero y un número ilimitado de veces.
 
   Coincidencia con "<p>", literalmente «<p>».

   Un solo carácter que sea un "carácter de espacio en blanco" (espacios, tabuladores y saltos de línea) «\ s *», entre cero y un número ilimitado de veces, tantas veces como sea posible «*».

Haga coincidir la expresión regular siguiente y capture su coincidencia en el número de referencia 2 «(<img [^ <] +?)»:

   Coincidencia con "<img" literalmente «<img».

   Cualquier elemento que NO sea un "<" «[^ <] +?», entre uno y un número ilimitado de veces «+?».

   Cualquier carácter que sea un "carácter de espacio en blanco" (espacios, pestañas y saltos de línea) «\ s *», entre cero y un número ilimitado de veces «*».

   Coincidencia con "</ p>", literalmente «</ p>».

Haga coincidir la expresión regular siguiente y capture su coincidencia en el número de referencia 3 «(. *)»:

   Cualquier carácter que no sea un carácter de salto de línea «. *», entre cero y un número ilimitado de veces «*».
```

Comment: No se está verificando la existencia de la etiqueta `<figure>`. El `(.*?)` del principio es innecesario. Además, la expresión fallaría con algo tan simple como una propiedad dentro del `<p>` o un comentario HTML. Y tampoco estaría reemplazando si hay más de un ocurrencia... No uses regex para analizar HTML! Estás copiando la respuesta aceptada, pero leíste el comentario del autor de la pregunta que dice "*Doesn't work, I give up. Thanks anyway.*"?

Comment: Estamos de acuerdo.